# Swift change text color to dark/lightmode

Tags: swift, textcolor, ios-darkmode

I am trying to change the text color in a UITextView from light grey to white/black.

So the new text color should be white when the dark mode is on and the text color should be black when the light mode is on.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can set the UIColor to .label

```
textView.textColor = .label
```

This should use the system label colour which is back against a white background and vice versa

You can also create your own dark/light colours in the assets file.
[image]

And then use them in code or the interface builder.

```
textView.textColor = UIColor.init(named: "myBlueColor")
```